# how to show link in html tag <a>

Tags: javascript, html

i am creating a html href link , but it show whole code in page

that is not show only the  link it show whole link

CODE :

```
 {
      id:10,
      name:'Google Chrome Extension',
      description:'Clip information from any webpage, through a custom google chrome extension.<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackby-webclipper/kjkhpjfgbiedbaohfklagjmcdjhamoje" > Download it from here.</a>',
      category:'Apps',
      status:0,
    },
```

it show link as

[image]

i want to show only  link inside  tag **Download it from here**

any one solve it, thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you take the value from a JSON and use it in your template.
Also, the description field looks like it is interpreted as a string and not as html content.
In order to properly track down the issue when seeking support you need to show how you represent that field in your HTML template, as the JSON you've shown is not HTML

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are appending the description from your JSON as [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText). Instead, You need to pass the description as [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to parse the HTML correctly.

**With innerHTML**

```js
document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += 'Clip information from any webpage, through a custom google chrome extension.<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackby-webclipper/kjkhpjfgbiedbaohfklagjmcdjhamoje" > Download it from here.</a>';
```

```html
<div id="add"> </div>
```

**With innerText** (your case which doesn't parse the HTML)

```js
document.getElementById("add").innerText += 'Clip information from any webpage, through a custom google chrome extension.<a href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackby-webclipper/kjkhpjfgbiedbaohfklagjmcdjhamoje" > Download it from here.</a>';
```

```html
<div id="add"> </div>
```